# Is the While programming language with bounded number of variables Turing complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, turing-completeness

In our lecture it was proven that WHILE-Programs are turing-complete. In short a WHILE-Program only allows the following:

```
Variables             x1,x2,...  (initially all 0 and can only be positive)
Constants c           0,1,2,3,...
Assignment            xi := c
Addition/Subtraction  xi := xj + c, xi := xj - c
while-loops           while(xi != 0) { ... }
```

Now we restrict the Language to k-VARIABLE-WHILE meaning that only a bounded number of variables can be used.
Is 100-VARIABLE-WHILE turing-complete? I think it isn't but I am not quite sure which function I can construct that needs more than 100 variables.

Comment: I suggest you start by thinking about 1-variable-WHILE and 2-variable-WHILE.  As a warmup: What can you say about 1-variable-WHILE?

Comment: @D.W. 1 Variable while is not turing complete because if one where to calculate for 2*x for a given variable x since you need one variable that adds up and one that counts down to terminate the loop